# Spring Boot heap dump error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring Boot 1.4.1, using spring boot gradle plugin, therefor it is using spring framework 4.3.3. Loading my application, I'm getting this error, it is driving me nuts:

```
[timestamp=23:49:24.983] [thread="main"] [session="undefined"] [request="undefined"] [level=WARN ] [logger=o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] [class=org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext] [line=549] 
- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'heapdumpMvcEndpoint': Could not bind properties to HeapdumpMvcEndpoint (prefix=endpoints.heapdump, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint@29897daf failed:

    Property: endpoints.heapdump.path
    Value: null
    Reason: may not be null


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I have no idea what parts of my code show to you guys, this error is freaking me out. If somebody has any idea, I can start sending my build file, my Application class, etc.

The error says something about a bean named 'heapdumpMvcEndpoint' and a property called endpoints.heapdump.path. I tried adding 'endpoints.heapdump.path' to my application properties, and it didn't work.

Comment: When I checked this "http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.html" I could see  `@ConfigurationProperties(value="endpoints.heapdump")` can you try creating a endpoints.heapdump file and put the mentioned property there?

Comment: I tried creating a endpoints.heapdump, and endpoints.heapdump.properties. I will try again, but that didn't work.

Comment: And I don't know who voted with -1 this question. I hate that kind of people, when they just come in, vote -1 without any comment or suggestion or justification. Totally non-solidary and unhelpful.

Comment: Add your `application.properties`.

Comment: @Perimosh totally agree. it is annoying people down vote  without knowing the right intention of question and answers. If we know who did this we could have done the same for them :)

Comment: We fixed the issue. We have to put this in our property file:

endpoints.heapdump.enabled=false
endpoints.logfile.enabled=false

The log file was added because after adding the heapdump property, and log file started to happened. This is a hack, for sure... so sad.